# How to detect google map animation finish?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, animation

I am animating position change in google map with following code;

The map is setup as;

```
GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: _cameraStartPos,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _mapController.complete(controller);
      },
    )
```

animation;

```
_cameraEndPlace = CameraPosition(target: widget.endPos, zoom: 8);

final GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;

controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_cameraEndPlace));
```

How do I detect when the animation is completed?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`animateCamera` returns a `Future`, use `then` on it.

```
controller.animateCamera(...).then((_) {
  // Your code
  }
);
```

Comment: this is wrong answer because "The returned Future completes after the change has been started on the platform side" for animateCamera as stated in docs

Comment: @HenadziRabkin I found it works as expected on iOS but not Android somewhat strangely.